# How can I measure the x axis movement of a carousel in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to measure the movement of my card across it's parent width. The X axis is not updating on click. Here are the code snippets. The main goal is to do something when the Client component is not visible on the screen. I've been trying to use getBoundingClientRect in the useRect hook. My best guess is that the hook dependency is not correct or the refs are not being passed successfully. Sorry I couldn't reduce the code down any more.

App.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks'
import { createRef } from 'preact/compat';
import './app.css'
import Client from './components/Client';
import { useRect } from './hooks/useRect';

export function App() {
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState<number>(0)

  function moveCard(prev: number) {
    setTranslate(prev += 20)
  }
  const contentRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const carouselRect = useRect(contentRef)
  const {right: carouselEndPoint} = carouselRect;

  return (
    <>
    <button class='bg-slate-300 absolute top-2 left-2 ' onClick={() => {
      moveCard(translate)
    }}> Click to call function</button>
      <div ref={contentRef} className="grid grid-cols-4 bg-slate-200 gap-3 grid-flow-col w-4/5 mx-auto overflow-clip">
        <Client carouselEndPoint={carouselEndPoint} translate={`${translate}%`} setTranslate={setTranslate} name="1"/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Client.tsx

```
import logo from '../assets/preact.svg'
import { useEffect } from 'preact/hooks'
import { useRect } from '../hooks/useRect'
import { StateUpdater, createRef } from 'preact/compat'

export interface ClientProps {
  name: string
  translate: string
  setTranslate: StateUpdater<number>
  carouselEndPoint: number
  width?: string | number
  // contentRef?: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
}

function Client({name, translate, setTranslate, carouselEndPoint}: ClientProps) {

  const contentRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const val = useRect(contentRef)
  const {left: clientX} = val;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(val);
    if(clientX >= carouselEndPoint) {
      console.log('hidden');
    }
  }, [translate])
  
  return (
      <div className="flex flex-col basis-auto bg-slate-300 items-center drop-shadow-md rounded-md w-full place-content-center transition-transform ease-linear duration-1000 overflow-clip" style={`transform: translateX(${translate})`} 
      ref={contentRef}>
        {/* client card */}
        <img className='h-full w-full' src={logo}/>
        <h3 className="text-5xl">{name}</h3>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Client;
```

useRect.tsx

```
// source: https://gist.github.com/morajabi/523d7a642d8c0a2f71fcfa0d8b3d2846
import { RefObject } from 'preact'
import { useLayoutEffect, useCallback, useState } from "preact/hooks";

type RectResult = {
  bottom: number;
  height: number;
  left: number;
  right: number;
  top: number;
  width: number;
};

function getRect<T extends HTMLElement>(element?: T): RectResult {
  let rect: RectResult = {
    bottom: 0,
    height: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0,
  };
  if (element) rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect;
}

export function useRect<T extends HTMLElement>(
  ref: RefObject<T>
): RectResult {
  const [rect, setRect] = useState<RectResult>(
    ref && ref.current ? getRect(ref.current) : getRect()
  );

  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    setRect(getRect(ref.current)); // Update client rect
  }, [ref]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    if (!element) return;

    handleResize();

    if (typeof ResizeObserver === "function") {
      
      const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => handleResize());
      resizeObserver.observe(element);
      return () => {
        if (!resizeObserver) return;
        resizeObserver.disconnect();
        // resizeObserver = null;
      };
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize); // Browser support, remove freely
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lied in the fact that I had named the ref in App.tsx and the ref in Client.tsx the same. This caused react to return two possible refs each time which made it impossible to update the x value. I also had to update the useEffect dependencies.